# Array merging / inserting not working

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, loops

Now here's two array that i do have:

```
first one: 
"workingHours": [
                {
                    "opening": "09:30",
                    "closing": "13:30",
                    "dayName": "sunday"
                },
                {
                    "opening": "",
                    "closing": "",
                    "dayName": "monday"
                },
                {
                    "opening": "",
                    "closing": "",
                    "dayName": "tuesday"
                },
                {
                    "opening": "10:30",
                    "closing": "06:30",
                    "dayName": "wednesday"
                },
                {
                    "opening": "01:00",
                    "closing": "08:00",
                    "dayName": "thursday"
                },
                {
                    "opening": "",
                    "closing": "",
                    "dayName": "friday"
                },
                {
                    "opening": "",
                    "closing": "",
                    "dayName": "saturday"
                },
            ],
```

```
Second one: 
            "discount": [
                {
                    "from_time": "13:00:00",
                    "to_time": "14:50:00",
                    "discount": "20",
                    "dayName": "wednesday"
                },
                {
                    "from_time": "06:13:16",
                    "to_time": "04:14:11",
                    "discount": "20",
                    "dayName": "monday"
                },
                {
                    "from_time": "05:10:15",
                    "to_time": "06:10:17",
                    "discount": "20",
                    "dayName": "tuesday"
                },
                {
                    "from_time": "06:59:16",
                    "to_time": "04:19:11",
                    "discount": "20",
                    "dayName": "monday"
                }
            ],
```

Now I want output like this:

```
Wanted Output: 
 "workingHours": {
    "opening": "",
    "closing": "",
    "dayName": "monday"
    {
        "from_time": "06:13:16",
        "to_time": "04:14:11",
        "discount": "20",
        "dayName": "monday"
    },
    {
        "from_time": "06:59:16",
        "to_time": "04:19:11",
        "discount": "20",
        "dayName": "monday"
    }
},
```

```
The output that is coming right now: 

"workingHours": [
                {
                    "opening": "09:30",
                    "closing": "13:30",
                    "dayName": "sunday"
                },
                {
                    "0": {
                        "from_time": "06:13:16",
                        "to_time": "04:14:11",
                        "discount": "20",
                        "dayName": "monday"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "from_time": "06:59:16",
                        "to_time": "04:19:11",
                        "discount": "20",
                        "dayName": "monday"
                    },
                    "opening": "",
                    "closing": "",
                    "dayName": "monday"
                },
                {
                    "0": {
                        "from_time": "05:10:15",
                        "to_time": "06:10:17",
                        "discount": "20",
                        "dayName": "tuesday"
                    },
                    "opening": "",
                    "closing": "",
                    "dayName": "tuesday"
                },
                {
                    "0": {
                        "from_time": "13:00:00",
                        "to_time": "14:50:00",
                        "discount": "20",
                        "dayName": "wednesday"
                    },
                    "opening": "10:30",
                    "closing": "06:30",
                    "dayName": "wednesday"
                },
                {
                    "opening": "01:00",
                    "closing": "08:00",
                    "dayName": "thursday"
                },
                {
                    "opening": "",
                    "closing": "",
                    "dayName": "friday"
                },
                {
                    "opening": "",
                    "closing": "",
                    "dayName": "saturday"
                }
            ],
```

Here's my code:

```
    foreach ($returnDataAns['workingHours'] as $key => $value) {
        # code...

        foreach ($returnDataAns['discount'] as $key2 => $value2) {
            # code...

            if ($value['dayName'] == $value2['dayName']) {
                # code...
                array_push($returnDataAns['workingHours'][$key], $value2);
            }

        }
    }
```

Any idea how can I do that? I just wanna remove those 0:  1: keys!

Comment: When you say not working, *what* isn't working? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I suggest that you take a little time to take the [tour] and read the [ask] page. There are some rules in this site, to help for content quality and so that questions can be answered more easily. In your case, you should have included your attempt at solving/searching solution to your problem in the question itself, as questions asking to write the code for you are considered off-topic on the site. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I made a foreach loop for both arrays, then compared it's dayName value, if matched then push second array's value in first one.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: I see your edit now. You want to remove 0 and 1 keys? What is supposed to replace the 0 and 1? That is how arrays work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the desired output...

```
$arr1 = json_decode('[
        {
            "opening": "09:30",
            "closing": "13:30",
            "dayName": "sunday"
        },
        {
            "opening": "",
            "closing": "",
            "dayName": "monday"
        },
        {
            "opening": "",
            "closing": "",
            "dayName": "tuesday"
        },
        {
            "opening": "10:30",
            "closing": "06:30",
            "dayName": "wednesday"
        },
        {
            "opening": "01:00",
            "closing": "08:00",
            "dayName": "thursday"
        },
        {
            "opening": "",
            "closing": "",
            "dayName": "friday"
        },
        {
            "opening": "",
            "closing": "",
            "dayName": "saturday"
        }
    ]', true);

$arr2 = json_decode('[
        {
            "from_time": "13:00:00",
            "to_time": "14:50:00",
            "discount": "20",
            "dayName": "wednesday"
        },
        {
            "from_time": "06:13:16",
            "to_time": "04:14:11",
            "discount": "20",
            "dayName": "monday"
        },
        {
            "from_time": "05:10:15",
            "to_time": "06:10:17",
            "discount": "20",
            "dayName": "tuesday"
        },
        {
            "from_time": "06:59:16",
            "to_time": "04:19:11",
            "discount": "20",
            "dayName": "monday"
        }
    ]', true);

$finalArray = [];
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $day) {
    $subArray = [];
    foreach ($arr2 as $key2 => $dayData) {
        if ($day['dayName'] === $dayData['dayName']) {
            $subArray[] = $dayData;
        }
    }
    $finalArray[$key] = !empty($subArray) ? $finalArray[$key] = [$day, $subArray] : [$day];
}

echo '<pre>';
echo '$finalArray ' . print_r($finalArray, true);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>';
echo '$finalArray json_encoded ' . print_r(json_encode($finalArray), true);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

This will give you the following JSON string from `json_encode` output:

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "opening":"09:30",
         "closing":"13:30",
         "dayName":"sunday"
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "opening":"",
         "closing":"",
         "dayName":"monday"
      },
      [  
         {  
            "from_time":"06:13:16",
            "to_time":"04:14:11",
            "discount":"20",
            "dayName":"monday"
         },
         {  
            "from_time":"06:59:16",
            "to_time":"04:19:11",
            "discount":"20",
            "dayName":"monday"
         }
      ]
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "opening":"",
         "closing":"",
         "dayName":"tuesday"
      },
      [  
         {  
            "from_time":"05:10:15",
            "to_time":"06:10:17",
            "discount":"20",
            "dayName":"tuesday"
         }
      ]
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "opening":"10:30",
         "closing":"06:30",
         "dayName":"wednesday"
      },
      [  
         {  
            "from_time":"13:00:00",
            "to_time":"14:50:00",
            "discount":"20",
            "dayName":"wednesday"
         }
      ]
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "opening":"01:00",
         "closing":"08:00",
         "dayName":"thursday"
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "opening":"",
         "closing":"",
         "dayName":"friday"
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "opening":"",
         "closing":"",
         "dayName":"saturday"
      }
   ]
]
```

Comment: It gives same output as my code but leaves the key, I just wanna remove those keys, any idea about it?

Comment: @JimKasprowicz Yes, I understand what you need now -  have updated my answer :)

Comment: @JimKasprowicz also updated with the beautified `json_encode` output for your inspection

Comment: @JimKasprowicz I saw you accepted my answer then unaccepted... any reason why? I have given what you asked for right?

Comment: Ah! Glad you are now sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you the expected output.
I use array_combine and array_column to make the first array associative.
The second array has to be looped to create an array that can be merged with the first array.

Lastly I use array_values to remove the associative.

```
foreach($discount as $val){
    $discount2[$val['dayName']][] = $val;
}  

$res = array_values(array_merge_recursive(array_combine(array_column($WH, "dayName"), $WH), $discount2));

var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/Q2fqe

Comment: I see the link you've provided. But even in the page, the associative array has keys, like [0]=> and [1]=>. I dont want it, I just want it without that keys.

Comment: That is not possible, as I wrote in comments to your question, that is how arrays work. Also that is the opposite of associative, it's indexed.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, indexes and not associative. But thank you for the code. I appriciate that.

Comment: If you must remove them you can use regex to remove it. See "before and after": https://3v4l.org/4BWvt

Comment: @Jim why are you trying to remove something that is part of array standards? What is the difference? When you json_decode the string without the 0 and 1, PHP will create them anyways.